# Can I travel to UK with Permesso di Soggiorno

Tags: uk, schengen, italy, eu-citizens, italian-residents

I am non-EU nationality, but married to Italian nationality, and I have Permesso di Soggiorno mentioned (MOTIVI FAMILIARI)

Is it allow me to enter UK with my wife as per subject 10,20 of law? or need for travel permit?